# Positioning of objects in the space with html and css

Tags: html, css, optimization

I'm trying to position some objects (in this case, are popovers from Bootstrap) and i move them in the space with css utilizing the pixels.

```
#dot{
    top: 60px;
    left: 650px
}
```

I tried also the *em*, but i was wondering if there is another and more efficient method.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can use percentage ```%``` whenever I have to position an object a large distance away I use percentage

Comment: Add parent position relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use values relative to viewport width and height.
ex : top : 4vh;
left : 6vw;

here , 4vh means 4% of viewport height and similarly 6vw means 6% of viewport width.

so if the viewport changes then the positioning will be done according to the new width and height.
But make sure that **position** property is set on the element because for top/left/right/bottom to work, position property must be set on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are providing top and left value that work only when you specified the position either absolute,relative and so on.. What you are trying now is directly apply top and left to static position and top,left,right,bottom only work for all position value except static position.